# how to make my win app in windows taskbar's notification area

Tags: c#

I've created one win app that exe file run successfully 
but now i want to make it all time active when windows start up
and i want to display it in windows task bar' notification area.
how could iachive this thing Pls. suggest me...

Answer (score 1):

To lunch the application in Windows Startup : Set an Entry in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run with application with Keyname as the application name and Value as the location of the path with executable name.

To set the System Notification area : Use Notify Icon Control. Set the Icon of the Control to set it in Notification area.